# Action on blur except when specific element clicked with react OR how to get clicked element onBlur

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to prevent onBlur event when I click on a specific element:

```
<input type="text" onBlur={<call when I click outside of element except when I click on a specific element>} />
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

What you could do is give the element that would stop the call an ID and then check for that ID via event.relatedTarget.id

```
    const doSomething = (event) => {
        if(event.relatedTarget.id === "badButton"){
            return
        }
        //Do things
    }

    return(
        <div className="DashboardHeader" onBlur={(e) => doSomething(e)}>
            <button id="badButton">newbutton</button>
        </div>
    )
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Can we use ref to pass badButton?

Comment: @MasihJahangiri i'm not sure what you mean, the element that the current element 'loses' focus to is in the event that is fired in onBlur.